# Sql Server cte error "Subquery returned more than one value."

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

This question is a continuation of the same effort to code my first cte that I mentioned in a couple other recent posts. In a nutshell, I'm working through a couple compiler errors for the query below. I'm now getting the error "Subquery returned more than one value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." But what I've come up with below seems "legal" to me based on my current abilities... any help would be great. BTW I either get that error, or Visual Studio 2010 shuts down when I try to run this...

```
WITH Symb AS
(
     SELECT Symbol
     FROM tblSymbolsMain
),

DatesNotNeeded AS
(
     SELECT Date
     FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol inner join Symb on
         tblDailyPricingAndVol.Symbol = Symb.Symbol
),

WideDateRange AS
(
     SELECT TradingDate
     FROM tblTradingDays
     WHERE (TradingDate >= dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDateTime()) AND (TradingDate <= dbo.LatestAvailableDataDownloadDateTime())
),

DatesNeeded AS
(
     SELECT TradingDate
     FROM WideDateRange wdr
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DatesNotNeeded d where d.Date = wdr.TradingDate)
)

SELECT Symb.Symbol, DatesNeeded.TradingDate
FROM Symb CROSS JOIN DatesNeeded
```

And my functions, as requested:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.LatestAvailableDataDownloadDateTime()
    RETURNS date
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT DATEADD(hour, 18, MAX(TradingDate)) AS LatestTradingDateAvailForDL 
    FROM tblTradingDays
    GROUP BY TradingDate
    HAVING (DATEADD(hour, 18, MAX(TradingDate)) < GETDATE()))
END

ALTER FUNCTION dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDateTime()
    RETURNS date
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT DATEADD(hour, 18, MIN(TradingDate)) AS TrDate
    FROM tblTradingDays
    HAVING (DATEADD(hour, 18, MIN(TradingDate)) > dbo.LatestDataDownloadDate()))
END
```

Comment: Can you post the code behind `NextAvailableDataDownloadDateTime` and `LatestAvailableDataDownloadDateTime`?

Comment: @StatsViaCash - Found the problem. You're grouping by the very column you're trying to find the max of. This will just return every row where `dateadd(hour, 18, tradingdate) < getdate()`. I changed your Next function just to make it clearer as well, instead of doing the `having`. The `where` predicate is much faster :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions are returning more than one value. Try this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.LatestAvailableDataDownloadDateTime()
    RETURNS date
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT DATEADD(hour, 18, MAX(TradingDate)) AS LatestTradingDateAvailForDL 
    FROM tblTradingDays
    WHERE (DATEADD(hour, 18, TradingDate) < GETDATE()))
END
```

And:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDateTime()
    RETURNS date
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT DATEADD(hour, 18, MIN(TradingDate)) AS TrDate
    FROM tblTradingDays
    WHERE (DATEADD(hour, 18, TradingDate) > dbo.LatestDataDownloadDate()))
END
```

Comment: As of the first couple passes, I think we're in business. :) I'm swapping out my current read for a sql server book tonight. Thx.

Answer (score -2):

Your subselect has a select *, which returns all columns. subselects need to deal with one column and row, ie:
select cartype from cars where cartype = 'Honda'

good luck,
speeves

Comment: It's in a `not exists`--this isn't the problem. You can return multiple columns to an `exists`.

Comment: Thanks, Eric! I'm always learning. I didn't catch the EXISTS :P